# overriding malloc, free and calloc cause recursion in Linux

Tags: c, linux, recursion, memory-management, malloc

I have overridden the functions `malloc`, `calloc` and `free` functions in Linux platform as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void* (*MALLOCFN)(size_t);
typedef void* (*CALLOCFN)(size_t, size_t);
typedef void* (*CALLOCFN)(size_t, size_t);
typedef void (*FREEFN)(void *);
MALLOCFN real_malloc = (MALLOCFN) 0;
CALLOCFN real_calloc = (CALLOCFN) 0;
FREEFN real_free = (FREEFN) 0;
void *get_realfn(const char *fnm)
{
  void *pfunc = (void *) NULL;
  printf("searching for original %s\n", fnm);
  pfunc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, fnm);
  if (pfunc) printf("found original %s\n", fnm);
  else printf("not found original %s\n", fnm);
  return pfunc;
}
void *malloc(size_t s)
{
  printf("called malloc\n");
  if(real_malloc == NULL) real_malloc = (MALLOCFN) get_realfn("malloc");
  if (real_malloc) return real_malloc(s);
  else return NULL;
}
void *calloc(size_t s1, size_t s2)
{
  printf("called calloc\n");
  if(real_calloc == NULL) real_calloc = (CALLOCFN) get_realfn("calloc");
  if (real_calloc) return real_calloc(s1, s2);
  else return NULL;
}
void free (void * ptr)
{
  printf("called free\n");
  if(real_free == NULL) real_free = (FREEFN) get_realfn("free");
  if (real_free) real_free(ptr);
}
int main()
{
  char * c1 = (char *) malloc(400);
  char * c2 = (char *) malloc(400);
  free(c2); free(c1);
  return 0;
}
```

The C program (testalloc.c) is built using g++ 4.9.2 version of compiler:

```
g++ -g testalloc.c  -ldl -o testalloc;
```

The first few lines of output shown is as below, it enters into infinite recursion and crashes:

```
called malloc
searching for original malloc
called free
searching for original free
called free
searching for original free
called free
searching for original free
called free
searching for original free
called free
. . . .
```

Please suggest how to avoid the recursion.

Comment: gcc, wrap option.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` function may allocate memory. So when you call `printf` *before* the "real" function pointers are not assigned, it comes into your interposed functions resulting in infinite recursion. So do not use `printf` statements in the interposing functions.

If you really need to print something, use `syscall(2)`, which would bypass stdio library functions.

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

...

syscall(SYS_write, STDOUT_FILENO, "searching for original\n",
                                  sizeof "searching for original\n" - 1);
```

Comment: Why bother with `syscall( SYS_write...)`?  Just use `write()`.

Comment: Probably. Habit I suppose.

Comment: That's better, can dlsym cause calling malloc or calloc? My debugger shows a call from malloc to eventually dlsym then to calloc causing into infinite recursion, can I avoid calling overriden malloc/calloc from dlsym?

Comment: `dlsym` doesn't allocate unless it fails (current glibc implementation). So yes, it's possible. If you want to make it safe, you probably need to provide a separate allocator for dlsym. Look at some existing libraries (such as TCmalloc, Jemalloc, etc) for how it's done.

Comment: it seems dlsym is failing, how do I let dlsym drive not into this trouble?

Comment: Your code appears to locate the correct libc functions for me. How are you compiling and what glibc version?

Comment: @usr, building using: g++ -g testalloc.c  -ldl -lrt -lpthread -o testalloc and libgcc version 4.8.5. probably -lrt is causing  this trouble, but this is needed as we are using pthreads and semaphores as well

Comment: Not necessarily a fix but why are you using `g++` instead of `gcc`? Why do you need `-lrt` as you aren't using any from it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159230/discussion-between-dr-debasish-jana-and-usr).

Comment: @P.P Re: "`dlsym` doesn't allocate unless it fails (current glibc implementation)". This appears to have changed; at least in Ubuntu 20.04's glibc-2.31, the code uncondtitionally `calloc()`s the "last result" buffer inside `_dlerror_run() if it isn't already allocated.